# Eval invoked by a bash script file

Tags: bash, eval

Hi I'm creating a bash script to improve my job. If I have some files in a directory such as

```
file1.dat
file2.dat
file3.dat
file1.inp
file2.inp
file3.fal
```

I must digit in a shell the following command

```
PBS_nastran ver=20101 mem=48Gb mod=i8 i=file1.dat
PBS_nastran ver=20101 mem=48Gb mod=i8 i=file2.dat
PBS_nastran ver=20101 mem=48Gb mod=i8 i=file3.dat
PBS_abaqus ver=6133 ncpu=16 j=file1.inp
PBS_abaqus ver=6133 ncpu=16 j=file2.inp
PBS_falancs j=file1.fal
```

I've created a symple script

```
code='nastran'
case $code in 
   abaqus)  command="PBS_abaqus ver=6133 ncpu=16 j="
            ext=".inp";;
   nastran) command="PBS_nastran ver=20101 mem=48Gb mod=i8 i="
            ext=".dat";;
   falancs) command="PBS_falancs j="
            ext=".fal";;
esac
file_list=$(ls * | grep "$ext$")
file_list=${file_list//"./"/}
file_list=$(echo $file_list | tr " " "\n")

for file in $file_list
do 
   command=$command$file
   eval $command
done
```

this it's ok and work correctly. The next step in a optimization process it's to put the code in a *.sh file and I create this

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in 
   abaqus)  command='PBS_abaqus ver=6133 ncpu=$3 j='
            ext='.inp';;
   nastran) command='PBS_nastran ver=20101 mem=48Gb mod=i8 i='
            ext='.dat';;
   falancs) command='PBS_falancs j='
            ext='.fal';;
esac
if [ -z $2 ] 
then
   file_list=$(ls | grep -E "[0-9]{8}_[[:alnum:]].*_RUN_[[:alnum:]].*${ext}$")
   file_list=${file_list//"./"/}
   file_list=$(echo $file_list | tr " " "\n")
else
   file_list=$2
fi
for file in $file_list
do 
   command=$command$file
   eval "$command"
done
```

but if I lunch script "./script.sh nastran" there is an error:
./lancia.sh: line26: PBS_nastran: command not found
I think that the problem is in the interpretation of blank space but I don't understand the way to fix it.
Thank for your help

Comment: Two questions: (1) Does this file have execute permissions? (2) Was this written on Windows or Unix?

Comment: Your first thought when using `eval` should be "What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: The best way to debug a shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. It will then display every command as it is executing, so you can see all the variables being expanded.

Comment: For Joe c. The file is written in windows but after The copy in linux I've used the command chmod +rx script.sh and sed -i  -e 's/\r $//' script.sh

Answer (score 1):

You should rarely need to use `eval`, and this is no exception. You can store a command *name* in a variable, but you should not store an entire command *line*. Put the arguments in an array to ensure they remain properly quoted.

Also, do not try to parse the output of `ls`; use patterns to match the files you want. (It is unfortunate, though, that you can't use bracket expressions like `{8}` with patterns.)

```
#!/bin/bash
num_cpus=${3:-1}

case $1 in 
   abaqus)
       cmd_name=PBS_abaqus
       cmd_options=( ver=6133 "ncpu=$num_cpus")
       file_option="j"
       ext='.inp'
       ;;
   nastran)
       cmd_name=PBS_nastran
       cmd_options=( ver=20101 mem=48Gb mod=i8)
       file_option="i"
       ext='.dat'
       ;;
   falancs)
       cmd_name=PBS_falancs
       cmd_options=()
       file_option="j"
       ext='.fal'
       ;;
   *) echo "Unrecognized name '$1', aborting" >&2
      exit 1
esac

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
   file_list=( [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]_[[:alnum:]]*_RUN_[[:alnum:]]*$ext )
else
   file_list=( $2 )  # I'm assuming here $2 is intended to be a pattern
fi
for file in "${file_list[@]}"; do
do 
   "$cmd_name" "${cmd_options[@]}" "$file_option=$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try your suggestions but unfortunately the problem remain